# (WMI) ExecMethod out parameter - ResultingSnapshot is NULL irrespective of the result of the call, Why?

Tags: c++, wmi

I am using WMI to create an RCT Checkpoint. Below is the code snippet. The problem is when I call the method `Create Snapshot` using `ExecMethod`the checkpoint gets created but the `ResultingSnapshot` to still points to `NULL`.

Since the call is asynchronous (as the return value from `pOutParameters` is 4096) I have also waited till the job gets completed in `WaitForJobCompletion` but `pOutParameters` is not updated and still, the `ResultingSnapshot` is NULL.

Basically, I need this `ResultingSnapshot` for creating a reference point. If there is any other way to do it, I can write it, need guidance though.

I am new to WMI, any help or lead is appreciated.

```
HRESULT hr;
CComPtr<IWbemClassObject> pInParams;
CComPtr<IWbemClassObject> pOutParameters;
IWbemCallResult *pResult = 0;

// Set Method Paramters
this->GetMethodParams(L"Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService", L"CreateSnapshot", &pInParams);

IWbemClassObject * pVirtualSystemSnaphotSettingData = NULL;
hr = m_pWbemServices->GetObject(L"Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotSettingData", 0, NULL, &pVirtualSystemSnaphotSettingData, &pResult);

IWbemClassObject * pInpInstOfSnapshotSettingData = NULL;
hr = pVirtualSystemSnaphotSettingData->SpawnInstance(0, &pInpInstOfSnapshotSettingData);

VARIANT consistencyLevel;
VariantInit(&consistencyLevel);
V_VT(&consistencyLevel) = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&consistencyLevel) = SysAllocString(L"1");
hr = pInpInstOfSnapshotSettingData->Put(L"ConsistencyLevel", 0, &consistencyLevel, 0);
VariantClear(&consistencyLevel);

VARIANT elementName;
VariantInit(&elementName);
V_VT(&elementName) = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&elementName) = SysAllocString(L"rhel-1");
hr = pInpInstOfSnapshotSettingData->Put(L"ElementName", 0, &elementName, 0);
VariantClear(&elementName);

hr = m_pWbemServices->PutInstance(pInpInstOfSnapshotSettingData, 0, NULL, &pResult);

BSTR objString = NULL;
hr = pInpInstOfSnapshotSettingData->GetObjectText(0, &objString);
BSTR ArgNameTwo = SysAllocString(L"SnapshotSettings");
VARIANT v;
V_VT(&v) = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&v) = objString; 

hr = pInParams->Put(ArgNameTwo, 0, &v, 0);

VARIANT vtProp;
m_pVmWbemClassObject->Get(L"__Path", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);

wprintf(L"Affected System : : %ls", (LPWSTR)vtProp.bstrVal);
HRESULT hres = pInParams->Put(L"AffectedSystem", 0 , &vtProp, NULL);

VARIANT var;
VariantInit(&var);
V_VT(&var) = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&var) = SysAllocString(L"2");


CHK_HRES(pInParams->Put(L"SnapshotType", 0, &var, 0));


IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumOb = NULL;
hr = m_pWbemServices->ExecQuery(
BSTR(L"WQL"),
BSTR(L"select * from Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService"),
WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
NULL,
&pEnumOb);
IWbemClassObject *pclsObj1 = NULL;
ULONG uReturn1 = 0;

while (1)
{
    HRESULT hr = pEnumOb->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj1, &uReturn1);

    if (0 == uReturn1)
    {
        break;
    }

    IWbemCallResult *pCallResult = NULL;
    IWbemClassObject *pResObj = NULL;

    CComBSTR path(this->GetStrProperty(L"__PATH", pclsObj1));

    hr = m_pWbemServices->ExecMethod(path, L"CreateSnapshot", 0, NULL, pInParams, &pOutParameters, &pCallResult);



    /* cout << "check1 : " << hex << hr << endl;
    hr = pCallResult->GetResultObject(0, &pResObj);
    cout << "check2" << endl;*/

    this->WaitForJobCompletion(pOutParameters);
   }

cout << "\nSnpshot Complete" << endl;
}
```

**EDIT**
I found that the SnapshotType Parameter is not set correctly it should be 32768 and I have used the following way to convert uint16 to Variant but no Success and I get `0x80070057 Incorrect Parameter` Error.

```
VARIANT var;
VariantInit(&var);
V_VT(&var) = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&var) = SysAllocString(L"32768");

hr = pInParams->Put(L"SnapshotType", 0, &var, CIM_UINT16);
```

Comment: I got t  know from here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a01b3952-8d6b-4c7c-b507-6f18be7b8d7d/how-to-get-a-snapshot-instance-after-create-a-snapshot-by-wmi?forum=winserverhyperv that the new snapshot is associated with Job Object which is returned but how to do it ?

Comment: I feel the SnapshotType Parameter is not correct not should be 32768. But how to convert uint16 to Variant is another Question.

Comment: What is `WaitForJobCompletion`? If that's your code, can you post it?

Comment: Just waiting for the job to complete. So I check the status if it says job complete it exit @ministic

Comment: Well if there is a bug in here it's probably in that function, so if you still need help you should post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HRESULT GetRelated(PWSTR sAssociatePath, PWSTR sResultClass, IWbemClassObject** ppResultObject)
{
CStringW query;
query.Format(L"associators of {%s} where ResultClass = %s", sAssociatePath, sResultClass);

CComPtr<IEnumWbemClassObject> pEnumOb;

HRESULT hr = m_pWbemServices->ExecQuery(
    BSTR(L"WQL"),
    CComBSTR(query),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
    NULL,
    &pEnumOb));
ULONG uReturn = 0;
CComPtr<IWbemClassObject> pObject;
hr = pEnumOb->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pObject, &uReturn);
return hr;
}
// Call the GetRelated function above with the __PATH parameter of JOB
CComPtr<IWbemClassObject> pOutParam = NULL;
CHK_HRES(this->ExecMethod(pHyperVObject, L"ConvertToReferencePoint", pInParams, &pOutParam, NULL));
CComVariant jobPath;
CHK_HRES(pOutParam->Get(L"Job", 0, &jobPath, NULL, NULL));
CComPtr<IWbemClassObject> pResult;
GetRelated(jobPath.bstrVal, L"Msvm_VirtualSystemReferencePoint", &pResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide a `ppCallResult` parameter. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392103(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ppCallResult [out] If NULL, this is not used. If ppCallResult is
>   specified, it must be set to point to NULL on entry. **In this case, the
>   call returns immediately with WBEM_S_NO_ERROR.** The ppCallResult
>   parameter receives a pointer to a new IWbemCallResult object, **which
>   must be polled to obtain the result of the method execution using the
>   GetCallStatus** method. The out parameters for the call are available by
>   calling IWbemCallResult::GetResultObject.

Therefore you need to use `GetCallStatus` on `pCallResult` until the method has finished and then `GetResultObject` to get the out parameters:

```
LONG status;
while ((hr = pCallResult->GetCallStatus(1000, &status)) == WBEM_S_TIMEDOUT);
/* check hr and status here */
hr = pCallResult->GetResultObject(0, &pResObj);
```

or use WBEM_INFINITE:

```
LONG status;
hr = pCallResult->GetCallStatus(WBEM_INFINITE, &status);
/* check hr and status here */
hr = pCallResult->GetResultObject(0, &pResObj);
```

Alternatively provide `NULL` instead of `pCallResult` and it will be a synchronous call where `pOutParameters` will be set:

```
hr = m_pWbemServices->ExecMethod(path, L"CreateSnapshot", 0, NULL, pInParams, &pOutParameters, NULL);
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, still the ResultingSnapshot is NULL

Comment: @MilindW There has to be detailed error messages then. What's the value of hr and what does `GetErrorInfo()` say?

Answer (score 0):

Was SnapshotType=32768 giving error to you?
Because snapshot is not created when I use this Snapshot Type.

The following log is getting created:

Checkpoint creation failed for 'Ubuntu1' because an invalid checkpoint type has been specified. (Virtual machine ID 5C773BB5-B630-48B4-AB9E-71C548F3FAE4)

Edit: I am not sure if it will help but this solved my problem:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/160321/wmi-createsnapshot-not-working-with-snapshottype-3.html

Comment: @Liger Sorry, for the inconvenience. But did you found an alternative? Because I am also trying to make a recovery snapshot and I am not able to use 32768.  And using 2 it gives me a standard snapshot.