# Convert uint16 to WMI Variant for CreateSnapshot Method

Tags: c++, wmi

I want to call CreateSnapshot Method which is a call to provider but I am stuck as I cannot set the input parameter for Snapshot Type which is expected as uint16. This is passed using a Variant. The code snippet is below.

```
VARIANT var;
VariantInit(&var);
V_VT(&var) = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&var) = SysAllocString(L"32768");

hr = pInParams->Put(L"SnapshotType", 0, &var, CIM_UINT16);

cout << "\nValue Set Is: "<<var.uintVal<<endl;
```

I am not able to pass the required value. Any points on what I am doing wrong ?

Note: Put method is working fine with HRESULT as 0 but CreateSnapshot is unsuccessful.

**EDIT**

Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService Class -> CreateSnapshot has the following prototype

```
uint32 CreateSnapshot(
[in]      CIM_ComputerSystem           REF AffectedSystem,
[in]      string                           SnapshotSettings,
[in]      uint16                           SnapshotType,
[in, out] CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData REF ResultingSnapshot,
[out]     CIM_ConcreteJob              REF Job
);
```

Comment: You may want to clarify a few things: What is the prototype of CreateSnapshot? What class is it a method of? What is pInParams in your code?

Comment: Edited the question for the information @Mr.C64 I am following this question to take a snapshot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776105/wmi-execmethod-out-parameter-resultingsnapshot-is-null-irrespective-of-the-r

Comment: The inParams are `AffectedSystem, SnapshotSettings,SnapshotType,` @Mr.C64 I am Following this to take a snapshot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776105/wmi-execmethod-out-parameter-resultingsnapshot-is-null-irrespective-of-the-r

Answer (score 0):

```
BSTR paramName3 = L"SnapshotType";
VARIANT var;
var.vt = VT_UI2;
var.iVal = (uint16_t)32768;

hresult = pInClass->Put(paramName3,
    0,
    &var,
    CIM_UINT16);
if (FAILED(hresult))
{
    string msg = "Failed to set property.";
    throw std::exception(msg.c_str());
}
VariantClear(&var);
```

as question，convert unit16 to varint and it's work